# Putting an image view over another in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I am trying to come-up with an app which requires putting(by drag and drop) an image inside another but i don't want to replace the first image. Instead i want to make the second image as a subpart of first image. Also one should be able to drag it again and drop it outside the first one. 
I am not getting any related article. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a FrameLayout .inside FrameLayout you can declare how many ImageView element you want the top ImageView only be visible or you can pull it to front for visibility of that ImageView.